# Transacting bulk publishing Spring JMS and Websphere MQ

Tags: transactions, ibm-mq, jmstemplate

I need to send multiple messages at once to N topics. The messages know how to route themselves. If any of the publications fails, all of the prior publications need to rollback. Is this possible on Websphere MQ and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "any of the publications fails" you mean the delivery of the publication to the QMgr, then put all the messages under a single unit of work and then issue a `COMMIT`.

If by "any of the publications fails" you mean the final delivery of the messages to the subscribers then no.  This is asynchronous messaging.  The basic idea of async messaging  is the decoupling of the apps sending and receiving the messages.  It is by design that the sending app doesn't know at `PUT` time whether the receiving app can get the message or not.  Pub/Sub takes that one step further by allowing publishers and subscribers to dynamically join or leave without affecting existing message distribution.

In an async messaging design if there is a need to account for delivery to some number of recipients, one would generally use a distribution list instead of Pub/Sub (because if you know in advance who the subscribers are and it doesn't change a list is sufficient), conformation messages to acknowledge receipt, and compensating transactions to back out error conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I figured a transaction shoukd work. Unfortunately getting an experiment environment is a long process.

Comment: "...getting an experiment environment is a long process."  Why?  Do you know that MQ for Developers is free?  Or is it more about company policy and not having admin on your own workstation?  If it is just a matter of getting the software, click the [tag:websphere-mq] tag, then click Learn More. I've provided links to the free downloads, documentation, etc.

Comment: I didn't know that existed. I've asked management if that is usable. I saw MQ Light. But figured that would not be an apples to apple environment.

Comment: MQ Light is definitely not the same.  Hopefully Management will let you use the MQAdv4Dev.  It is a full-function, non-expiring MQ with all the same components you use in Production.  The only restriction is there's no support for the Developer version but then if you had a problem and could duplicate it in a normally-licensed Dev or QA you could get support there.